# Encrypting configuration sections

Tags: configuration, web-config, app-config

I'm trying to programmatically encrypt configuration sections of App.config and Web.config files. In the following code,  I set the path configuration file I want to edit in the configFilePath variable and then expect it to encrypt the connectionStrings section.

> ```
>         var config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(configFilePath);
>         var section = config.GetSection("connectionStrings");
>         if (section.SectionInformation.IsProtected)
>         {
>             section.SectionInformation.UnprotectSection();
>             section.SectionInformation.ForceSave = true;
>             config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);
>             ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("connectionStrings");
>         }
>
>         section.SectionInformation.ProtectSection("DataProtectionConfigurationProvider");
>         section.SectionInformation.ForceSave = true;
>         config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);
>         ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("connectionStrings");
> ```

This runs fine without any errors but makes no changes to the given file. It's like it's not  really accessing the file I want to access.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right, answering my own question...

The code was indeed not opening the right config file. To do that we need to use `ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration()` instead of `ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration()`.

So, the first line of the code above changes to:

```
var map = new ExeConfigurationFileMap { ExeConfigFilename = configFilePath };   
var config = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(map, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
```